# Django AJAX Form submission is always invalid

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax, forms

I have a Django Project with a view that contains two forms that I want to be submitted with two separate ajax requests. The first ajax request is actually supposed to fill in one value of the second form which this does successfully. Also, the second form has a few initial values that I later plan on making hidden so the user only sees the necessary fields to fill in after submitting the first form.

I am passing in an "`ajax_type`" keyword after checking for "`request.is_ajax()`" and "`request.method == 'POST`' within my view to determine if the ajax type is the first ajax request or the second one. My second ajax request makes use of a model form that is supposed to create a new instance of my model upon validation.

My View:

```
def canadaTaxEntries(request):

    newest_record = LAWCHG.objects.aggregate(Max('control_number'))
    newest_control_number = newest_record["control_number__max"]
    print(newest_control_number)

    today = date.today().strftime("1%y%m%d")
    current_time = time.strftime("%H%M%S")
    #print(today)
    #print(current_time)

    initial_data = {
        'control_number': (newest_control_number + 1),
        'item_number': None,
        'vendor_tax_code': None,
        'expiration_flag': 1,
        'charge_category': None,
        'charge_desc_code': None,
        'country': 'US',
        'state': None,
        'city': None,
        'county': None,
        'charge_amount': None,
        'charge_uom': 'CA',
        'charge_percentage': 0.0,
        'apply_flag': 1,
        'beg_del_date': None,
        'end_del_date': None,
        'rev_date': today,
        'rev_time': current_time,
        'est_date': today,
        'est_time': current_time,
        'program_id': 'BI008',
        'operator_id': 'FKRUGER',
    }

    canada_tax_form = CanadaTaxForm(request.POST or None, initial=initial_data)

    if request.is_ajax():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            canada_tax_form = CanadaTaxForm(request.POST or None, initial=initial_data)

            data = json.load(request)
            #item_number = request.POST.get('itm', False)
            ajax_type = data.get("ajax_type")

            if ajax_type == "screen_item":
                print('1st request')
                num = data.get("item")
                itmnum = int(num)
                return screen_item_ajax(itmnum)
            
            elif ajax_type == "tax_entry":
                print("2nd request")

                if canada_tax_form.is_valid():
                    print("VALID")
                    canada_tax_form.save()
                else:
                    print("NOT VALID")
                    print(canada_tax_form.errors)

                controlnum = data.get("control_num")
                itemnum = data.get("item")
                ventaxnum = data.get("vend_tax")
                return canada_tax_entries_ajax(request, controlnum, itemnum, ventaxnum)


    context = {
        "canada_tax_form":canada_tax_form,
    }

    return render(request, "html/canadaTaxEntries.html", context)
```

My ajax requests:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#item_num_form', function (e) {
    let item_number = document.getElementById("item_number").value

    console.log(item_number)
    e.preventDefault()
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/canada/",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            ajax_type: "screen_item",
            item: item_number,
        }),
        headers: {
            "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
            "X-CSRFToken": getCookie("csrftoken"),
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data)
            console.log("AJAX Worked!")

            let description = data.item_info[0].item_description;
            document.getElementById("description").innerHTML = "Item Description: " + description;

            let upc_num = data.item_info[0].upc_14_long;
            document.getElementById("upc_num").innerHTML = " UPC Number: " + upc_num;

            document.getElementById("id_item_number").value = item_number;

            function getTH() {
                const column = table_headers;
                const head = document.querySelector('thead');
                let tags = "<tr>";
                for (i = 0; i < column.length; i++){
                    tags += `<th>${column[i]}</th>`;
                }
                tags += "</tr>"
                head.innerHTML = tags;

                getTD();
            }

            function getTD() {
                const body = document.querySelector('tbody');
                let tags = "";

                data.existing_tax_records.map(d => {
                    tags += `<tr>
                    <td>${d.beg_del_date}</td>
                    <td>${d.end_del_date}</td>
                    <td>${d.charge_amount}</td>
                    <td>${d.charge_uom}</td>
                    <td>${d.apply_flag}</td>
                    <td>${d.charge_category_id}</td>
                    <td>${d.charge_desc_code_id}</td>
                    <td>${d.vendor_tax_code}</td>
                    <td>${d.control_number}</td>
                    </tr>`
                })
                body.innerHTML = tags;
            }
            getTH()
        }
    })
})


$(document).on('submit', '#tax_form', function (e) {
    let control_number = document.getElementById("id_control_number").value
    let item_number = document.getElementById("id_item_number").value
    let vendor_tax_code = document.getElementById("id_vendor_tax_code").value

    console.log(control_number)
    e.preventDefault()
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/canada/",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            ajax_type: "tax_entry",
            control_num: control_number,
            item: item_number,
            vend_tax: vendor_tax_code,
        }),
        headers: {
            "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
            "X-CSRFToken": getCookie("csrftoken"),
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data)
            console.log("2nd AJAX Worked!")
            console.log("Is form valid???")
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error)
            console.log("2nd AJAX Failed")
        }
    })
})
```

Both my ajax requests are returning a success message so the trigger to submit my second form is being hit. I think the problem has to do with my form being wiped before I submit it even though I have all the input fields filled when hitting the submit button for the second form. I am not sure if I am initializing my form incorrectly but I am stumped as to why my form never passes the validation check.

Finally printing out to the console with "`print(canada_tax_form.errors)`" after the validation check prints out the following which leads me to believe my form is being wiped. How could I avoid this?

```
NOT VALID
<ul class="errorlist"><li>control_number<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>item_number<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>vendor_tax_code<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>expiration_flag<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>charge_category<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>charge_desc_code<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>country<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>state<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>charge_amount<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>charge_uom<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>charge_percentage<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>apply_flag<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>beg_del_date<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>end_del_date<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>rev_date<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>rev_time<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>est_date<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>est_time<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>program_id<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>operator_id<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>
```

Comment: I'm sure this isn't the problem, but you don't need `JSON.stringify` around your object that you are sending via ajax. You can pass the object itself.

Comment: OK thanks, but yeah that doesn't help with why my form is always invalid... any ideas at all as to why this is the case?

Answer (score 0):

In your ajax you are sending the following:

```
    data: JSON.stringify({
        ajax_type: "tax_entry",
        control_num: control_number,
        item: item_number,
        vend_tax: vendor_tax_code,
    }),
```

Your form, however, will be expecting

1)the keys to the data values to have the same names as the fields in the form definition.  To judge by the errors, they are named differently eg, control_number instead of control_num, so they are not getting assigned during the form setup from the request.POST

2)all the required fields of CanadaTaxForm to be filled in. This may be compounded by the fact that, because  you are sending POST data, your initial fields are not being read. As the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/forms/api/#initial-form-values) say: These values are only displayed for unbound forms, and they’re not used as fallback values if a particular value isn’t provided.

To fix this, you might also write hidden fields in your tax_records table to hold any additional data CanadaTaxForm requires, and capture those values as 'data' as you do the new ones for ajax submission. Or you could  have a cut down CanadaTaForm with only the submitted data required as fields if the user can't really change the others, adding anything else when its time to create the new object (it's hard to be specific  as to the best course without seeing the form or template)